# Problema de cierre de aplicación en LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Estoy creando un pequeño juego en Android de tipo plataformas en 2D. En este momento estoy implementando los botones en pantalla para mover al personaje, pero cuando inicio la aplicación, se cierra automáticamente.
El error parece que tiene que ver con la creación del stage.

Este es el código de la clase de los controles:

```
public class Controles {
    Viewport viewport;
    Stage stage;
    boolean salto, izquierda, derecha;
    OrthographicCamera cam;

public Controles() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, cam);
    stage = new Stage(viewport, PantallaJuego.batch);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    Table table1 = new Table();
    Table table2 = new Table();
    table1.left().bottom();
    table2.right().bottom();

    Image flechaizquierda = new Image(new Texture("flechaIzquierda.png"));
    flechaizquierda.setSize(50, 50);
    flechaizquierda.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            izquierda = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            izquierda = false;
        }
    });

    final Image flechaderecha = new Image(new Texture("flechaDerecha.png"));
    flechaderecha.setSize(50, 50);
    flechaderecha.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            derecha = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            derecha = false;
        }
    });

    Image flechasalto = new Image(new Texture("flechaIzquierda.png"));
    flechasalto.setSize(50, 50);
    flechasalto.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            salto = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        }
    });

    table1.add();
    table1.add(flechaizquierda).size(flechaizquierda.getWidth(), flechaizquierda.getHeight());
    table1.add();
    table1.row().pad(0, 5, 0, 5);
    table1.add();
    table1.add(flechaderecha).size(flechaderecha.getWidth(), flechaderecha.getHeight());
    table2.add();
    table2.add(flechasalto).size(flechasalto.getWidth(), flechasalto.getHeight());
    table2.row().padRight(5);
    table2.add();

    stage.addActor(table1);
    stage.addActor(table2);
}

public void draw() {
    stage.draw();
}


public boolean isDerecha() {
    return derecha;
}

public boolean isIzquierda() {
    return izquierda;
}

public boolean isSalto() {
    return salto;
}

public void resize(int ancho, int alto) {
    viewport.update(ancho, alto);
}
}
```

Precisamente el error me señala a la línea de `stage = new Stage(viewport, PantallaJuego.batch);` de Controles y `controles = new Controles();` de PantallaJuego.

Y este es el código de la pantalla principal;

```
public class PantallaJuego extends ApplicationAdapter implements Screen  {

private MarioBros game;
public static SpriteBatch batch;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

private OrthographicCamera gamecam, cam;
private Viewport gamePort, viewport;
private HUD hud;

private TmxMapLoader maploader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
Controles controles;


private Mario player;

private Music musica;

public PantallaJuego(MarioBros game) {

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("MarioyEnemigos.pack");
    this.game = game;
    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH / MarioBros.PPM, MarioBros.V_HEIGHT / MarioBros.PPM, gamecam);
    hud = new HUD(game.batch);
    controles = new Controles();


    maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = maploader.load("nivel1mario.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/MarioBros.PPM);

    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth()/2, gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2, 0);


    world = new World(new Vector2(0,-10), true);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    player = new Mario(world, this);

    new B2WorldCreator(world, map);



    world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());

    musica = MarioBros.manager.get("Audio/Música/Super Mario World - Overworld Theme Music (FULL VERSION).mp3", Music.class);
    musica.setLooping(true);
    musica.play();

}

public TextureAtlas getAtlas() {
    return atlas;
}

@Override
public void show() {
}


public void handleInput(float dt) {

    if(controles.isDerecha())
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

    if(controles.isSalto())
        MarioBros.manager.get("Audio/Sonidos/Super Mario Bros- Mario Jump Sound Effect.mp3", Sound.class).play();
    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

    if(controles.isIzquierda())
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);



}

public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput(dt);

    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
    gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;
    cam.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

    player.update(dt);
    hud.update(dt);


    if(Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.Android)
        controles.draw();

    gamecam.update();
    cam.update();
    renderer.setView(gamecam);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();
    b2dr.render(world, cam.combined);
    b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    player.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();


}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);

    controles.resize(width, height);

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    b2dr.dispose();
    hud.dispose();

}
}
```

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar, estaría muy agradecido. Gracias.

Comment: Diego, Bienvneido a SO en Español, podrias indicarnos que error te da, asi te podemos ayudar mas

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado, pero ahora me salta este error: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.globapps.supermarioclon.Screens.PantallaJuego.update(PantallaJuego.java:117) at com.globapps.supermarioclon.Screens.PantallaJuego.render(PantallaJuego.java:136) at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46) at com.globapps.supermarioclon.MarioBros.render(MarioBros.java:41) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:‌​223) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124‌​) Qué puede ser?

Comment: Cual es esta linea PantallaJuego.java:117??

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: No olvides marcar como respuesta aceptada las contribuciones de los usuarios que te hayan ayudado, en este caso la respuesta de [Angel Angel](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4669/2027) con el boton en forma de V del lado izquierdo, asi ayudaras a futuros usuarios a encontrar mas rapido la la solución :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podria poner el log, pero por lo que puedo ver creo que su error esta en esta linea

```
public static SpriteBatch batch;
```

trate de inicializar el Batch

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
```

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#constructor.summary

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites#spritebatch

---

En la llamada a `stage = new Stage(viewport, PantallaJuego.batch);`
puede leer en el link de debajo sobre el segundo parametro (`throw new IllegalArgumentException("batch cannot be null.");`):

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java#L108

Comment: Ya está arreglado. Muchas gracias.